# vim: open fold with remote-silent

Tags: vim

I have this function to do inverse searches (from the pdf to Vim) when working with LaTeX documents in MS Windows:

```
function! ViewTex()
    if has('win32') || has('win64')
        let execstr = 'silent! !start SumatraPDF -reuse-instance '.
                    \ '-inverse-search "gvim --remote-silent +\%l \%f"'.
                    \ '%:p:r.pdf'
    endif
    exec execstr
endfunction
```

This works fine except that it will not open closed folds. So my question is: how to pass `normal zv` command to `--remote-silent`? I tried (without success) the following:

```
"gvim --remote-silent +\%l|normal\ zv \%f"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back to your first attempt, in most situations the Windows cmd.exe shell doesn't use '\' to escape anything. So I think you need to surround your init commands in quotes instead of backslash-escaping the spaces. Also, according to `:help --remote`, the commands in the init must be able to have a following '|' to separate them, meaning `normal` will not work unless surrounded with an `execute` command. So in your case something like this will eventually need to execute in the shell:

`gvim --remote-silent +"%l|exe 'normal! zv'" %f` (with the quotes included)

But I'm not sure whether this allows expansion as desired of %1 and %f.

***Edit:***

Or, use `foldopen!` instead of `exe 'normal! zv'` to avoid the need for spaces or `exe` at all. But, note this actually opens more folds than just `zv`; maybe that's OK for you.

From your comments, it looks like whatever platform you're using requires backslash-escaping any '%' characters, so:

`gvim --remote-silent +\%l|foldopen! \%f`

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* **The explanation below is slightly wrong** but the method is sound. I missed that the `--remote` family takes an optional "init" command argument; it's part of the `--remote-silent` command not a new argument to gvim. The explanation below fits for if it was a new argument to gvim.

---

The problem is that the Vim which runs to send the remote file will also run the `+...` command, rather than the Vim which actually edits the file. Try using `--remote-send` or `--remote-expr` after the `--remote-silent`, to send the commands you need to run after loading the file.

I.e. something like:

```
gvim --remote-silent myfile
gvim --remote-send zv
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing what you suggest but without success. I need to pass the following options to the PDF viewer: `gvim --remote-silent +%l;foldo! %f`